# WCF Service Application or WCF Service Library?

Tags: wcf, service

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between WCF Service application and WCF Service library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204365/what-is-the-difference-between-wcf-service-application-and-wcf-service-library)

I am really new to WCF and one of the things that are confusing me right now is the type of projects that we can create with Visual Studio when it comes to Web services.

I would like to know the difference between a WCF Service Application and WCF Service Library, and when to use each.

Throw into the mix the WCF Data Services and i feel even more confused. Ideally what i want to do is to use the best of the 3 to create a layer that will get data from a SQL Database to use with ASP.NET front end that can be consumed easy with JQuery. Which one should I start to learn first?

thanks.

- Alright. i found the answer.
  thanks

Comment: If you found your answer, either post it down below or close your question.  So the next person can find it :)

Comment: I don't see the option to close the question. So far i was the only one with this noob question. If someone else in the future wants to ask about it, i will be glad to respond with what i already know. :)

Comment: post your answer as an answer to your own question and mark it as the asnwer.

Comment: Hi Zinoo - I have the same question. Could you please post your answer?

Answer (score 2):

See [What is the difference between a WCF Service Application and a WCF Service Library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204365/what-is-the-difference-between-wcf-service-application-and-wcf-service-library)

Comment: You should have simply made this a comment, and probably flagged it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

WCF server application is hosted by development server, whereas WCF service library is host by WCF test client.