# Difference between WCF service library and WCF service application

Tags: .net, wcf, iis

I want to send a file from android to .NET server, will it make any difference if I use a WCF service application and WCF service library? (Further info: I am using IIS for hosting.)

Answer (score 12):

you need to use a wcf service application project and host it over IIS. If you are creating a WCF client library, you need to add another project in your solution and add reference of service in it to host. If you want to keep separate projects for service library and hosting project so that you can host it on some other hosting application also, you can go for second approach. other wise WCF service Application is enough for IIS hosting.

Comment: Is there any complications since IIS is an application and we are trying to host an application in another application? I have been told that since an application generates an .exe and library generates a dll, it could make some difference and some complications could arise, how true is this?

Comment: @user2818487, a web application project type in Visual Studio won't give you an .exe.

Comment: @LexLi... I know that, all I want to know is that will hosting a wcf service application in IIS cause any problem and does it make any difference from hosting a WCF service library in IIS?

Comment: @user2818487  A web application is something else than an .exe :). You need to use "WCF service application" in order to use it directly in IIS. A "WCF service library" needs a host project (e.g. application) before it can be used.

Answer (score 5):

A service application includes a website host already setup for you. A service library is a library of services that a host can reference and startup.

**[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204365/what-is-the-difference-between-wcf-service-application-and-wcf-service-library)** you can find the best explanation

Comment: My question is that will it cause any problem if I use IIS to host a WCF service application and is it in any way different form WCF service library hosting?