# Web Service in a Windows Service: Multithreading

Tags: .net, multithreading, web-services, windows-services

**Summary**: How parallel requests to a web service are managed when the host is a Windows Service?

I know a SOAP Web Service can be hosted within IIS, a Console application or a WinForms application. For one reason or another, these hosts are not available to me and I must host my Web Service within a Windows Service.

In case of IIS, I have read that the web server itself manages multiple parallel requests and assigns them different threads. I need to understand how this multithreading works in case of  Windows Service. Which component is responsible for it? Is it pool-based or something? How and where can I configrue pool-size etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term 'web service' is a broad. Please review [Web Service vs WCF Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351334/web-service-vs-wcf-service) for clarification.
In case your question is about WCF-based services, there is a good article on concurrency here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/89858/WCF-Concurrency-Single-Multiple-and-Reentrant-and.

To answer your questions:

The `System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost` is responsible for hosting the service. The ServiceBehavior attribute in app config or in code can be used to set the desired behavior, like so:

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
var yourServiceHost = new ServiceHost(yourService);
```

The threads are created from the thread pool. You can control the number of threads being used with `System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceThrottlingBehavior` or in the app config:

```
<serviceBehaviors>
 <behavior name="serviceBehavior"> 
  <serviceThrottling  maxConcurrentInstances="<your_max_instances>" maxConcurrentSessions="<your_max_concurrent_sessions>" /> 
 </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```

Comment: And I'm hosting WCF service in a Windows Service, so your assumption is correct.